# java.lang.NullPointerException when doing .getImage

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have been searching this site and Google for days and tearing my hair out wondering why this isn't working.  I am making a 2D rpg style game like FFII and am able to make a character walk around the screen using different images depending on the direction and the code worked fine until I put the `Image[]` in a new class to make it more usable for later coding.  Here is the part of the code that works perfectly:

```
package alpharpg;

import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class AlphaCharacterSheet extends AlphaConstants{                

    Image[] avatar;

public AlphaCharacterSheet() {      

            avatar = new Image[NUMOFAVATARS];
}

public void GetCharacter (int c){

        switch (c){
                case BARD:

                    ImageIcon tempii;


                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKMENU));
                    avatar[MENUAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBATTLE));
                    avatar[BATTLEAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKFRONT));
                    avatar[FRONTAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBACK));
                    avatar[BACKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKLEFT));
                    avatar[LEFTAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKFRONT));
                    avatar[FRONTWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKBACK));
                    avatar[BACKWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
                    tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKLEFT));
                    avatar[LEFTWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();


                default:
                break;
            }

    }
```

The call to `GetCharacter(BARD)` works and in `paint()` I draw it with

`drawImage(party.players[inputcounter].avatar[currentzone.avatarfacing],     currentzone.avatarx, currentzone.avatary, null);`

HOWEVER even though this works perfectly when I put it into

```
public Image[] img;

public void AlphaAvatar(){

    img = new Image[NUMOFAVATARS];

}

public void SetAvatar (int avatarid){


    switch (avatarid){

        case BARD:

        ImageIcon tempii;
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBATTLE));
        img[BATTLEAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKFRONT));
        img[FRONTAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBACK));
        img[BACKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKLEFT));
        img[LEFTAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKFRONT));
        img[FRONTWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKBACK));
        img[BACKWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
        tempii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKWALKLEFT));
        img[LEFTWALKAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();
```

Now in CharacterSheet I have AlphaAvatar avatar;

In `CharacterSheet()` I have `avatar = new AlphaAvatar();`

Then when `GetCharacter(BARD)` is called I make a call to `avatar.SetAvatar(BARD)` and it gives the error at the first `img[] = tempii.getImage();`

Any help as to why I can load the images through one class but not the other would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `SetAvatar` method you have `avtarid` as argument but your case is using `BARD`. Do this suppose to happen like that?

Comment: "BARD" is a constand defined elsewhere and I know that isn't the issue.  I've only put up a snippet of code as there is a LOT of it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the

```
public void AlphaAvatar(){

    img = new Image[NUMOFAVATARS];

}
```

by

```
public AlphaAvatar(){

    img = new Image[NUMOFAVATARS];

}
```

`public void AlphaAvatar()` is not a constructor, it is a method called `AlphaAvatar` that returns nothing... It explains why img was not initialized in it.

Comment: Nope, all the same package :-(

Comment: So the `this.getClass()` in the second example does return a class that is in the package alpharpg ? Which class it is ?

Comment: it returns alpharpg.AlphaAvatar which is the class it's being called from

Comment: And is `this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBATTLE)` `null` ? when you call `new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(FRANTIKBATTLE))`

Comment: Nope it isn't.  It has the path to my image

Comment: I see that `Image[]` img is public, do you have, by any chance some code that would set this property to null ?

Since `img[BATTLEAVATAR] = tempii.getImage();` cause an NPE, there is 3 possibilities:

 1. `img` is null
 2. `tempii` is null
 3. `tempii.getImage()` cause an NPE since the source code is:
    
        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }I doubt it is the case

Comment: Well through some more debugging I see that - Array "img" is null object - but I didn't get that error when assigning in the CharacterSheet class.  Is there a way to initialize the array?  I know I can't do "img[0] = new Image();"

Comment: The array is initialized in the `AlphaAvatar` constructor. Is there anywhere else in the code where this property is accessed ? And maybe set it to `null` ?

Comment: At no point in my code am I explicitly setting any part of the array to null, and I am initializing it with 'img = new Image[NUMOFAVATARS];' which I'm thinking doesn't set them to null as it would have given me the same error in the other class. - Thanks for all the awesome help btw I do appreciate it -

Comment: You are not initializing it, `public void AlphaAvatar()` is not a constructor. See my updated answer.

You should make the property img private if it is not accessed anywhere.

Comment: Yup that was it!!  Thanks for all your help, I'm sure I'll remember that if it comes up in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your ImageIcon (tempii) is null. Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugged to check the state of your objects?

Comment: *Correction* tempii is fine!!  It grabs the image data correctly.  The issues seems to be when I assign img[MENUAVATAR] = tempii.getImage() where MENUAVATAR = 0